# How to change format of Select list value in database

Tags: zend-framework2

I have a list of companies which im using while creating company reports as a select list.

I'm populating select list with database value with [KEY] => [Value] array types, which is working fine and in exchangeArray

```
\Zend\Json\Json::encode($morningreport->company)
```

this is how select list value is treated. Working fine.

Now the the value of company is stored ["2", "1"] in this format.

Is it zend defined way. If that so, how can I change it. Or any way for converting into string or array or so.

My requirement is to loop through this value and returned with the name based on this "2" and "1" IDS.

Note: 2 and 1 are the IDS of the comapnies. and select list was passed the array like :

```
'2' => 'companyA'.
'1' => 'companyB'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally found the answer,

```
\Zend\Json\Json::encode($morningreport->company)
```

encodes array into json format, so after fetching back this

```
$result = ["2"]
\Zend\Json\Json::encode($result);
```

decode jscon format and it will return back array.